# I don't understand why this simple program is outputting gibberish?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, parameter-passing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double T;
double V;
double WC(double T, double V);
void index(double WC(double T, double V));

    int main(void)
{
    cout<<"Please enter your T followed by your V"<<endl;
    cin>>T>>V;
    cout<<index;
}
double WC(double, double)
{
    if(V>4.8)
        return 13.12+0.6215*T-11.37*pow(V,0.16)+0.3965*T*pow(V,0.16);
    else
        return T;
}
void index(double WC(double,double))
{
    if (WC(T,V)<=0&&WC(T,V)>=-25)
    {
        cout<<"Discomfort";
    }
    if (WC(T,V)<-25&&WC(T,V)>=-45)
    {
        cout<<"Risk of skin freezing (frostbite)";
    }
    if (WC(T,V)<-45&&WC(T,V)>=-60)
    {
        cout<<"Exposed skin may freeze within minutes";
    }
    if (WC(T,V)<-60)
    {
        cout<<"Exposed skin may freeze in under 2 minutes";
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this is outputting random gibberish like "010F11B8", it's only supposed to print something based on input of temperature and wind velocity.

Comment: you are not calling your `index` function and printing out the address of the `index` function

Comment: Assuming you are in UNIX/Linux, this might be helpful: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/

Comment: To elaborate on `Ed S`'s point: What is `T`?  What is `V`?  What is `WC`?  What are you using only one prompt and taking the input simultaneously rather than prompt-input-prompt-input?  Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

[working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64c5b044724e269a)

to call the index function you need to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double T;
double V;
double WC(double T, double V);
void index(double WC(double T, double V));

int main(void)
{

    V = 5.0;
    T = -60.0;
    // declare a function pointer which accepts two doubles and returns a double
    double (*wcPtr)(double, double);

    // initialise function pointer
    wcPtr = &WC;

    cout << "Please enter your T followed by your V" << endl;

    // call function pointer
    index(wcPtr);
}
double WC(double T, double V)
{
    if(V>4.8)
        return 13.12+0.6215*T-11.37*pow(V,0.16)+0.3965*T*pow(V,0.16);
    else
        return T;
}
void index(double WC(double T,double V))
{
    if (WC(T,V)<=0&&WC(T,V)>=-25)
    {
        cout<<"Discomfort";
    }
    if (WC(T,V)<-25&&WC(T,V)>=-45)
    {
        cout<<"Risk of skin freezing (frostbite)";
    }
    if (WC(T,V)<-45&&WC(T,V)>=-60)
    {
        cout<<"Exposed skin may freeze within minutes";
    }
    if (WC(T,V)<-60)
    {
        cout<<"Exposed skin may freeze in under 2 minutes";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling `index`, you're printing its address.  Method calls require parens `index()`.

Comment: almost same wording as mine... BTW, `index` take argument

Comment: @BryanChen: I know it does.  You should have posted an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: I tried cout<<index(WC); but that doesn't work because "no operator matches these operands"?

Comment: @user2923961: Your function signaure should be `index(double (*f)(double, double));`, i.e., it takes a pointer to a function which takes two doubles and returns a double